# Dapper : must declare the scalar variable in Select command

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

The following query

```
Connection.Query<User>("select * from User where Login=@login and Passwd=@passwd", new { login = _login, passwd=_passwd})
```

returns the following error

> Must declare the scalar variable @login

The User model :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Passwd { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

My problem was coming from the SQL connection

My connection string was

```
new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User Id=sa;Password=****;");
```

I've changed it to

```
new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User Id=sa;Password=****;");
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Does `_login` have a value when you stop there at a breakpoint?

Comment: @MarioGuadanhim this would be a capital sin in any sql database engine. Never ever concatenate strings to build sql commands

Comment: @Steve I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with SQL Server, seems to be working fine:

```
[Test]
public void simple_select_test()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=test"))
    {
        var result = conn.Query<User>(
            "select * from (select Id = 420, Login = 'foo', Passwd = 'bar') a where Login=@login and Passwd=@passwd",
            new {login = "foo", passwd = "bar"}).First();

        Assert.That(result.Login, Is.EqualTo("foo"));
        Assert.That(result.Passwd, Is.EqualTo("bar"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with PostgreSQL, all works fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=pass;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=TestUser;";
        var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        var _login = "someLogin";
        var _passwd = "somePass";

        connection.Open();
        var result = connection.Query<User>("select * from public.users where login=@login and password=@passwd", new { login = _login, passwd = _passwd });
        connection.Close();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}. Login: {item.Login}");
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Login like "some Login" works fine, and return expected result too.